# Android Scroller Issue

Tags: android

i've done a custom view group to display my menu in a different way :

it comes from the right of the screen.

I use scrollTo right now and it works fine, but i would like to get the scroll action animated, so i decided to add a scroller. but when i call :

```
mScroller.startScroll(0, 0, 100, 0, 1000);
```

nothing happends. scrollTo(100,0) did its job

Could you explain me why ? I basically have no more code to do what i want.
is it a problem ?

I've tried to do a simple animation : 
my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="100" >
```

my Java :

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.translate_menu_animation);
        animation.start();
```

but still, it does nothing.

Comment: Please provide a layout xml file with a scrollable area

Answer (score 1):

If a menu fitted all scrollable area then scroll not work. If you want animate your menu, you should use simple [view animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).

Comment: i've tried it and post it above, it still doesn't do anithing, do you know why ? it's the first time i use those

Comment: I have the feeling that i'm not clear, when i push the physical menu button, i want to make appear a menu layout from the right of the screen which is just at the right of my main layout. i've created a custom view group that put my menu layout at the right of my main layout. when i perform scroolTo, the viewGroup is moved forward to the left and then make appear my menu